# File size is not showing correctly while uploading file using multer in node

Tags: multer

```
{ avatar: 
   [ { fieldname: 'avatar',
       originalname: 'Screenshot from 2019-03-13 17-48-35.png',
       encoding: '7bit',
       mimetype: 'image/png',
       buffer: <Buffer ef bf bd 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52 00 00 05 56 00 00 03 00 08 02 00 00 00 40 5c ef bf bd ef bf bd 00 00 00 03 73 42 49 54 08 08 08 ... >,
       size: 438640 } ] }
```

This is the response in the server end where the size shows 438640 but when I checked from my pc file system it shows 244.7 kB .. any solution guys?

Answer (score 0):

Ok it is solved now. It was because of the file permission of linux system. Files was being corrupted , I created a new project and test it there it works fine there.

Comment: I am facing something similar in my virtual machine. What was the solution?